# How to delete Items in MongoDB / Mongoose & make sure to not end up with non-referenced objects in my DB?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

How do I delete an Document in MongoDB, which references other Documents?

Say I want to delete a `book`: The book has an `author` which it references, and also a table of contents which is a reference. Now when I delete the `book`, I will want to delete the `table of contents` for sure, but maybe not the `author`, since the same `author` might have written different books which are still in my database and are referencing this author, so I don't want to delete this.

But then the `author` object to-be-deleted may itself reference other objects, and the `table of contents` object too. It seems extraordinarily complicated then, to delete a single item in mongoose / mongodb? Or am I not getting something? Is there an easier way?

Is there a way for example to delete all objects in a collections, that are not referenced by anything else?

Comment: You use Postgres or another RDBMS.

Comment: Well I'm using MongoDB?

Comment: Mongo isn’t relational and neither is mongoose. Mongo schemas are document based, so you either store redundant info in each document (like author) or you manually, in code, check all the related collections and clean up data there.

Comment: You are right, and you have a fair point: I have started with Mongo initially and now am more and more often asking myself why, since it feels like my data is being pulled apart more and more and is way more relational than I initially thought. Nevertheless, Mongo is not JSON and it is recommended to pull data apart & store documents in different collections & reference them. And my question was about how deletion works in MongoDB, not about whether MongoDB is the right choice.